# How to build Boost 1.65 on Windows x64 with msvc 14.0

Tags: windows, boost, visual-studio-2015, 64-bit

I have to build **boost_1.65** with **msvc 14.0** in **x64** architecture, but I always get 32 mode. Unfortunately, I could not google a solution for my problem. The output I get is:

```
- 32-bit                   : yes
- arm                      : no
- mips1                    : no
- power                    : no
- sparc                    : no
- x86                      : yes
- symlinks supported       : yes
- C++11 mutex              : yes
```

I run with the following command in the VS2015 Native tools x64 prompt:

```
b2 -j8 toolset=msvc-14.0 address-model=64 threading=multi --build-type=complete install
```

I also try to use the following in my `project-config.jam` or `~/user-config.jam`:

```
using msvc : 14.0 : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\amd64\cl.exe ;
```

The above does not have an effect (and any other 64 folder I use). The only way to see 64-bit from the `b2` run is when I set something different than `using msvc : 14.0` e.g. `using msvc : lib64.14.0`  and call the `b2` with the modified toolset name. However, in this case I get binaries of the form `libboost_atomic-vc-mt-1_65` instead of `libboost_atomic-vc140-mt-1_65` and then msbuild fails to find the binaries.

> Is there any hidden setting that I need to prepare? Any suggestions?

Moreover, I noticed that when I use `using msvc : 14.1` I can get 64-bit and when I use `using msvc : 12.0` I get again 32-bit.

> Can it be some boost issue/constraint with v1.65? In v1.68 I did not see that behaviour?

Comment: I recall that issue building boost 1.65 with MSVC 14 at the time, so I just downloaded the relevant windows binary from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/)

Comment: Unfortunately these binaries miss mpi. So I have to build anyhow.